# What kind of C++ constant/macro is -1.#IND?

Tags: c++, function, math, pow

The Math "pow" function returns -1.#IND. What kind of error value is -1.#IND and how do I detect the error in an if-statement?

Comment: it might help if you told us what parameters you suppled to produce that result...

Comment: What did you pass in? `pow(0,-1)`?

Comment: @chris - wouldn't `pow(0, -1)` produce `-1.#INF` if I remember correctly?

Comment: @PeteBecker, I'm not too familiar with the way C++ does it, but in math, 0/0 is indeterminate, so I made that connection.

Comment: @chris - yes, 0.0/0.0 is indeterminate under IEEE-754, as is as infinity/infinity. `pow(0,-1)` is `1/0`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, *pow(0,-1) is 1/0* ooooooops. I'll just be hiding from humanity now.

Comment: @chris - not for long, I hope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-1.#IND` is the textual representation of [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) on Windows.

You can check if a float value is NaN with this small function:

```
// NaN never compares equal, not even to itself
bool is_nan(double d){ return d != d; }
```

(As @chris notes, if you have a C++11 compliant stdlib, you get [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) in `<cmath>`.)

In normal program flow, you shouldn't need to worry about NaN as long as you sanity-check your math inputs. Of course, you can also go the other way and just do your math calculations and check against NaN afterwards. :)

Answer (score 4):

The value you see is a representation for *NaN* or *not a number*. These values show up as a result of a floating point operation which has an undefined value. For example, `0.0 / 0.0` will yield a NaN. There are a number of other situations where a NaN is produced. If you want to determine if a floating point value is a NaN, you can test for them:

```
if (std::isnan(value)) {
    ...
}
```

There are few other other special values which can be produced as the result of floating point operations, e.g., positive or negative infinity and there are tests in `<cmath>` for these, as well.

Comment: `std::isnan(value)` tests for a NaN. `std::numeric_limits` doesn't have a way of testing for a NaN, but it has two members for generating them: `quiet_NaN()` and `signaling_NaN()`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I wasn't looking properly: of course, you are right! These are functions from C's library imported to C++ by `<cmath>`. I adjusted the response correspondingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

-1#IND normally happens when you have a /0 somewhere in your code.  Protect against it by checking all denominators or bases in pow functions with -ve exponents for 0's.

Once the division or pow operation has been completed, if you didn't check your inputs, check your outputs with:

```
if (output != output)  return 0; // or some default
else                   return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

`-1.#IND` is a NaN, not a number. NaNs arise for many reasons. Expressions such as 0.0/0.0 are indeterminate; you'll get a NaN if you try. The square root of -1 (or of any negative real) is pure imaginary; use the float or double `sqrt` function and you'll get a NaN as a result. Here the result is not indeterminate, but it is not real, either. It's a NaN.

Another way to express `sqrt(-1.0)` is `pow(-1.0, 0.5)`. This also generates a NaN.